# Python plot gantt chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a set of values and i need to create a gantt chart from it, values are like this

```
1   0,000000    4,219309    4,219309    8,988674    8,988674    10,848450
2   4,219309    7,414822    7,414822    12,430150   12,430150   14,198310
3   8,000000    10,478795   10,478795   15,417747   15,417747   17,297929
1   11,000000   14,257995   14,257995   19,009302   19,009302   20,873072
2   14,257995   17,410029   17,410029   22,304447   22,304447   24,123009
3   18,000000   20,494690   20,494690   25,678852   25,678852   27,521070
1   21,000000   24,197839   24,197839   29,070650   29,070650   30,889371
2   24,197839   27,269837   27,269837   32,357236   32,357236   34,232483
4   27,269837   30,432503   30,432503   35,207464   35,207464   37,120424
1   31,000000   34,215182   34,215182   39,079631   39,079631   40,928846
3   34,215182   37,219774   37,219774   41,988526   41,988526   43,868911
2   37,219774   40,423759   40,423759   45,411568   45,411568   47,280815
1   41,000000   43,647413   43,647413   48,378227   48,378227   50,217919
```

So the first value represent a machine. The second and third the start time and end time for process A and so forth with columns 4,5,6,7. Im using this script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from file into variables
cps, s_load, f_load, s_process, f_process, s_unload, f_unload = np.loadtxt('arena.txt', unpack=True)

# Map value to color
color_mapper = np.vectorize(lambda x: {1: 'red', 2: 'blue', 3: 'green', 4: 'black'}.get(x))

# Plot a line for every line of data in your file
plt.hlines(cps, s_load, f_load, colors=color_mapper(cps))
plt.show()
```

But i'd also like to differentiate colors between process in the same machine, not just between machines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you separated different CPU on Y axis, I think you don't need to set different color for every CPU:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from file into variables
cps, s_load, f_load, s_process, f_process, s_unload, f_unload = np.loadtxt('arena.txt', unpack=True)

# Plot a line for every line of data in your file
plt.hlines(cps, s_load, f_load, colors="red", lw=4)
plt.hlines(cps, s_process, f_process, colors="green", lw=4)
plt.hlines(cps, s_unload, f_unload, color="blue", lw=4)
plt.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

If you really want to set different color for CPU and process, you can:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from file into variables
cps, s_load, f_load, s_process, f_process, s_unload, f_unload = np.loadtxt('arena.txt', unpack=True)

colormap = {
    (1, 1):"r",
    (1, 2):"g",
    (1, 3):"b",
    (2, 1):"y",
    (2, 2):"m",
    (2, 3):"k",
    (3, 1):"r",
    (3, 2):"g",
    (3, 3):"b",
    (4, 1):"y",
    (4, 2):"m",
    (4, 3):"k",    
}  

color_mapper = lambda cps, p:[colormap[c,p] for c in cps]


# Plot a line for every line of data in your file
plt.hlines(cps, s_load, f_load, colors=color_mapper(cps, 1), lw=4, )
plt.hlines(cps, s_process, f_process, colors=color_mapper(cps, 2), lw=4)
plt.hlines(cps, s_unload, f_unload, colors=color_mapper(cps, 3), lw=4)
plt.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are only plotting a few gantt charts the package plotly has some good graphs as well. Most people like matplotlib but these look nicer. Use the code below to see an example or see their documentation at https://plot.ly/python/gantt/

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
  dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
  dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]

fig = ff.create_gantt(df)
py.iplot(fig, filename='gantt-simple-gantt-chart', world_readable=True)
```